# Adding multiple polylines to an MKMapView (Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin.ios, mkmapview, xamarin.forms, mkpolyline

I'm extending the example provided @ https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/maps/map-overlay/polyline/ to add multiple polylines to my map.

Everything works fine with a single polyline, but when I add the second, or add a polyline alongside an annotation, GetOverlayRenderer errors out with the error

```
"Value cannot be null.Parameter name: polyline"
```

It's erring out on line:

```
polylineRenderer = new MKPolylineRenderer (overlay as MKPolyline);
```

And when I look at the overlay object, it is:

```
{MapKit.MKOverlayWrapper}
BoundingMapRect: {{{62634939.7333333, 111606556.311973}, {745654.044444449, 848491.772016793}}}
Coordinate: {CoreLocation.CLLocationCoordinate2D}
Handle: 0x791ca560
Non-public members:
```

I don't understand why it works with one polyline, but when I add anything else to the map, it fails (first time through the method, also)

Here's the entire method where the error is occurring. I can provide more code but it works FINE with one line, just not with two. (I loop through a list of objects... if there's 1, it's fine.. if there is 2, it fails).

```
MKOverlayRenderer GetOverlayRenderer (MKMapView mapView, IMKOverlay overlay)
    {

        if (polylineRenderer == null) {
            try
            {

            polylineRenderer = new MKPolylineRenderer (overlay as MKPolyline);
            polylineRenderer.FillColor = UIColor.Blue;
            polylineRenderer.StrokeColor = UIColor.Red;
            polylineRenderer.LineWidth = 3;
            polylineRenderer.Alpha = 0.4f;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
        return polylineRenderer;
    }
```

Comment: It may be a bug possibly.  If you can zip it up and send over, I will take a quick look?  If so, my details are on my profile.

Comment: I'll email you direct, but here's the link for anyone else interested... 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5Tg3f2jpNBpbGFzVTFpZ2JQNFk/view  

This is a slightly modified version of the recipe (just moved the GPS coordinates to my area for a demo with a client). It works fine with one overlay (comment out line 55 of CustomMapRenderer.cs in the iOS project). If you add the second overlay, it doesn't display either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end result here was that the overlay passed to the method is a wrapper of sorts, and you need to get the "handle" property to get the actual overlay.

```
public override MKOverlayView GetViewForOverlay (MKMapView mapView, IMKOverlay overlayWrapper)
    {
    if (overlayWrapper != null) {
    var overlay = Runtime.GetNSObject(overlayWrapper.Handle) as MKOverlay;
    // Do Overlay Functions here
    }
```

The source of this came from https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/31616/what-is-mkoverlaywrapper-its-breaking-my-map-renderer

Answer (score 2):

For the delegate your setting for the `nativeMap.OverlayRenderer` remember that this is called for **every** overlay that you add.

When this delegate is invoked it will be passed the `IMKOverlay` it relates to.

Of which then you can either return a previously stored `MKOverlayRenderer`, or create a new one.

The reason your code is failing, when you attempt to add two overlays, is because you are trying to return the **same** renderer for **both** overlays, i.e. `polylineRenderer` variable in your code.

Just for demonstration purposes I've modified your `GetOverlayRenderer` to the following.  This isn't a good design, but illustrates the point I'm making above.

When you run this now, you will see one of your `MKPolyline` in `Red`, and the other in a `Yellow` color.

Add this in at class scope:-

```
private bool cblnIsTest = false;
```

and then modify your `GetOverlayRenderer` to the following:-

```
MKOverlayRenderer GetOverlayRenderer(MKMapView mapView, IMKOverlay overlay)
{
    MKPolylineRenderer polylineRenderer2 = new MKPolylineRenderer(overlay as MKPolyline);

    if (!cblnIsTest)
    {
        cblnIsTest = true;
        //
        polylineRenderer2.StrokeColor = UIColor.Yellow;
    }
    else
    {
        polyline Renderer.StrokeColor = UIColor.Red;
    }
    polylineRenderer2.LineWidth = 3;
    polylineRenderer2.Alpha = 0.4f;
    //
    return polylineRenderer2;
}
```

**Update 1:-**

As mentioned above, the code is not good design, and is to illustrate a point only.

Yes - you can re-use `MKOverlayRenderer`'s, however remember renderers are assigned to a specific `IMKOverlay` that is passed into your delegate.

You are trying to use the **same** renderer for **multiple** `IMKOverlay`'s.  It's just not possible.

Although you have an existing renderer, you **can't** assign it to a different `IMKOverlay` that is passed into your delgate as the `Overlay` property of the `MKOverlayRenderer` is **read-only**, and that's the reason why.

HTH.

Comment: I'll check that out... From some other reading I was doing on multiple overlays, I thought the whole point was TO REUSE the same MKPolylineRenderer, not create a new one for each overlay. Are you saying that each overlay (MKPolyline, MKCircle, etc.) needs it's own renderer? If so, it definitely explains my issue, but it goes against what I thought I'd read elsewhere (perhaps that was integrating some reusable renderers, though?).

Comment: @ChetatC2IT I've update my answer with more info (See **Update 1**).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
public override MKOverlayView GetViewForOverlay(MKMapView mapView, IMKOverlay overlay)
        {
            if (overlay is MKPolyline)
            {
                // return a view for the polygon
                MKPolyline l_polyline = overlay as MKPolyline;
                MKPolylineView l_polylineView = new MKPolylineView(l_polyline);
                MKPolylineRenderer l_polylineRenderer = new MKPolylineRenderer(l_polyline);

                l_polylineView.FillColor = UIColor.Blue;
                l_polylineView.StrokeColor = UIColor.Red;

                return l_polylineView;
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: I've tried that... never makes it past the if statement:

    "if (overlay is MKPolyline)"

I'm going to pull all my code out of the project I'm working on into something very minimal (maybe even the recipe Xamarin provides) and try that, unless anyone has a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

@Pete, now I get it, and that did the trick. For my ugly demo, here's what I landed at. It creates a new renderer every time it's called... not good form, but it demonstrates the code you made - essentially I moved my renderer from being scoped across the class to being recreated every time it's requested... bad form, and I'll clean this up to reuse renderers down the road, but it gets the job done for demonstration / understanding.

```
    MKOverlayRenderer GetOverlayRenderer (MKMapView mapView, IMKOverlay overlay)
    {
        //Moved the renderer here instead of being scoped at the class
        MKPolylineRenderer polylineRenderer= new MKPolylineRenderer (overlay as MKPolyline);
        polylineRenderer.FillColor = UIColor.Blue;
        polylineRenderer.StrokeColor = UIColor.Red;
        polylineRenderer.LineWidth = 3;
        polylineRenderer.Alpha = 0.4f;
        return polylineRenderer;
    }
```

And there they are!
[image: Multiple Overlays]

Comment: Turns out this was also a big part of the issue - I'm not sure how this relates yet, but I was getting an IMKOverlayWrapper in my real app instead of an IMKOverlay... I used the code below to convert this into an actual overlay that then had my necessary "polyline" property.

var overlay = Runtime.GetNSObject(overlay.Handle) as MKOverlay;

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/31616/what-is-mkoverlaywrapper-its-breaking-my-map-renderer