# Xamarin iOS - Mapkit ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35468177/adding-multiple-polylines-to-an-mkmapview-xamarin) but I am not sure how my code relates to the answers given in the other post.

I am using `MapKit` in `Xamarin iOS` to create a custom map for my Xamarin iOS project. I have a few different custom things happening at the moment, and am using `Polygons` `annotations` and now `circles` that are added to my map.

I have just started implementing adding `MKCircle` to my map, but when I try to add Circle Overlays to my map I am receiving this error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: polygon
```

I think it is being I trying to return the same overlay to two renderers, but I am not sure how to ammend this. **Here is my code:**

```
for(int i=0; i < hazards.Count; i++) //This adds 3 circles in my example
{
    LatLong ltlng = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LatLong>(hazards[i].coordinates);
    coords[i].Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(ltlng.latitude);
    coords[i].Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(ltlng.longitude);
    var overlay = MKCircle.Circle(coords[i], Convert.ToDouble(hazards[i].radius));
    nativeMap.AddOverlay(overlay); //this is the suspected problem
}
```

**And my renderer code here:**

```
    MKOverlayRenderer GetOverlayRenderer(MKMapView mapView, IMKOverlay overlayWrapper)
    {
        if (!Equals(overlayWrapper, null))
        {
            var overlay = ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObject(overlayWrapper.Handle) as IMKOverlay;
            polygonRenderer = new MKPolygonRenderer(overlay as MKPolygon)
            {
                FillColor = UIColor.Red,
                StrokeColor = UIColor.Blue,
                Alpha = 0.4f,
                LineWidth = 9
            };
        }
        return polygonRenderer;
    }
```

**Do I need to add something to my renderer code like this?:**

`circleRenderer = new MKCircleRenderer(overlay as MKCircle){};`

Comment: overlayWrapper is null, GetNSObject returns null, the result of GetNSObject can't be cast to an IMKOverlay, or overlay can't be cast to MKPolygon. If the implicit casts fail, you'll get null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears all your overlays are `MKCircle` based:

```
var overlay = MKCircle.Circle(coords[i]
```

In your `GetOverlayRenderer` you casting all overlays received as `MKPolygon` objects which will result in a null object.

```
polygonRenderer = new MKPolygonRenderer(overlay as MKPolygon)
```

You are then trying to create a `MKPolygonRenderer` render for each of your overlays which would not work if you actually did have an MKCircle-based overlay.

*If* all your overlays are `MKCircle` based, then yes use:

```
new MKCircleRenderer(overlay as MKCircle){};
```

Comment: Great thanks @SushiHangover, so something like a switch statement would be good in this case?

Comment: @BarneyChambers Yes, if there are different kinds of `IMKOverlay` being received by `GetOverlayRenderer` then a switch using "pattern matching" could be used, like in my example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46148412/4984832